# Scheduling Task in using C++ On linux and Windows machine

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am working on Gateway Simulator Application application.the gateway Streams the video to the client.Gateway Simulator can simulate the 1000 gateway.a user can issue the command like start the recording after 1 hour and record upto 1 hour or may be strem the video at 5'oclock.So basically scheduling the task.

This gateway will  run on both windows and linux.
Here for 1000 gateway there can be 1000 such request from the user.There need to save this schedule this task some where so that it can executed later.I wanted to know how to implement this.

I am using QT4 along alongwith C++ for this application.
Here I can't use any other third party lib .

How to implement this features in C++ or QT

Comment: Please finish your question, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QT, scheduling can be done with [QTime](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtime.html) and [QTimer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtimer.html).

- Simple: start a timer per scheduled event based on the difference between now and event-time
- more scalable (1000 requests): maintain a container of events and start 1 timer to the first event.

Comment: Thanks Stefaanv for reply.QT is fine for me and i have no objection using QT for scheduling task.for just sake of knowledge .can we implement the same in c++ without using QT and third party lib in both linux and windows.

Comment: Do you mean I need to matain 1000 timer?

Comment: You can maintain 1000 timers or you can sort 1000 Event-classes and use 1 timer.  In plain C++, you use can a separate thread and sleep before executing some action.