# Qt run at certain time?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a easy way to call a event at a given time in Qt? Or do I need to implement some loop to check the time?

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated, even if it's not using Qt

Comment: Well.. I have some idea about C#.. here, this can help you to understand.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307798/how-can-i-raise-an-event-every-hour-or-specific-time-interval-each-hour-in-ne

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392124/scheduling-task-in-using-c-on-linux-and-windows-machine

Comment: Thank you Wouter, I did a search just couldn't find the correct wording I suppose you could say. It gave me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) would help.

Something like this:

```
    QTImer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(1000);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerTimeout()));
```